# Cast from ? to T in Java

Tags: java, casting

I'm trying to use Generics to keep a good abstraction.

After moving around an "unchecked cast" between several classes, I had to choose which "unchecked cast" was the lesser evil and this is what I got:

```
public class DaoFactory {
    private static DaoFactory instance;
    private HashMap<String, Dao<?, BigDecimal>> registeredClasses = new HashMap<String, Dao<?, BigDecimal>>();

    private DaoFactory() {
    }

    public static synchronized DaoFactory getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new DaoFactory();

        return instance;
    }

    public <T> void registerDao(String daoId, Dao<T, BigDecimal> d) {
        registeredClasses.put(daoId, d);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Dao<T, BigDecimal> createDao(String daoId) {
        return (Dao<T, BigDecimal>) (registeredClasses.get(daoId)).createDao();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I added a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` where I get the "unchecked cast" warning.

Here's the problem: `registeredClasses` **can't** be `HashMap<String, Dao<T, BigDecimal>>` because I'd need to add the type parameter `T` to the `DaoFactory` class (it would be `class DaoFactory<T>`). And if I add that parameter, then `instance = new DaoFactory();` would need `<T>` too. But it is inside a static mathod (`DaoFactory` is a singleton), so I can't use `T`. So I use `HashMap<String, Dao<?, BigDecimal>> registeredClasses` instead of `HashMap<String, Dao<T, BigDecimal>> registeredClasses`.

So I have both the "`<T>`-world" and the "`<?>`-world" inside this factory class. So I have to cast from `Dao<?, BigDecimal>` to `Dao<T, BigDecimal>` and use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`. Do you think this is acceptable?

Comment: Well, the solution is fundamentally type-unsafe since `registeredClasses` is an inhomogeneous map, holding various types of Dao. That must bubble up *somewhere*.

Comment: It's quite strange, though, that you call `createDao()` on an instance of `Dao` to get a `Dao` of the same type.

Comment: There are classes that `extends Dao` (example: `Impl1Dao`) and they have their `createDao()` which `return new Impl1Dao();`

Comment: So a `Dao` is both a DAO and a DAO factory? That's a strange way to do it.

Comment: I follow this pattern http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html , look at the "Class Registration - avoiding reflection" section.

Comment: That pattern may work in some constrained cases where the instantiated  class is lightweight enough so it can double as a factory object. Normally DAO objects have database connection/transaction objects injected into them and are by no means lightweight. I don't like the conflation of unrelated concerns nevertheless. You could also have companion factory classes for each DAO.

Comment: With Java 8 all you'd need for a factory is a lambda.

Comment: Well, I use Hibernate with the common "HibernateUtil" class which is usually static or singleton, so I shouldn't have multiple heavy objects. However, what would you do in Java 7?

Comment: As I said, I'd use a companion factory class. It can be a small static class within the DAO class. But if you don't see any gain from it, stick with what you have. All this is unrelated to your question on type unsafety, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I am uncertain to which degree this is feasible, as you need a Class object to cast to; because of type erasure which turns T into Object.

```
public void registerDao(String daoId, Dao<Object, BigDecimal> d) {
    registeredClasses.put(daoId, d);
}

public <T> Dao<T, BigDecimal> createDao(Class<Dao<T, BigDecimal>> klazz,
                                        String daoId) {
    return klazz.cast(registeredClasses.get(daoId).createDao());
}
```

The `Dao` wrapping up is not helpfull here, as nicest would be to use `Class<T>`.

Comment: `createDao` is an instance method of a `Dao`, which perfectly well knows its class. You just need `dao.getClass().cast(...)` However, the whole casting shebang doesn't gain anything because the same cast already exists at the call site.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, though the question is to return a `Dao<>` of **T** - which cannot be done safely without at least a `class<T>`. I suspect that a `<T> T getT(Class<T> klazz)` might make more sense.

Comment: That's just about type inference, which will in some cases work without the type tag (and in others won't). So it's not about type safety.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't make a big difference, however the code posted by Joop doesn't give warnings. P.S. But it gives errors in the other classes :-D Somewhere I need a cast which gives a warning.